# how get Array json in kotlin from url

Tags: android, json, kotlin

am new in android studio " `kotlin` " , am try to get information from `url` data `json` , content `JSONObject` and `JSONArray` , my code Working fine with `JSONObject` , but i still have problem withe `JSONArray` .

this is my code for any one can help me to how can get JSONArray from my url

```
  fun buclick(view:View){
        val flightSearch=editText2.text.toString()
        val url="xxxxxxx-flight=$flightSearch"
    MyAsyncTask().execute(url)
    }


    inner  class  MyAsyncTask:AsyncTask<String,String,String>(){

        override fun onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute()
        }

        override fun doInBackground(vararg p0: String?): String {
            //تمرير بيانات هنا
            try {
                val url=URL(p0[0])
                val urlConnect = url.openConnection() as HttpURLConnection
                urlConnect.connectTimeout=500

                val dataJsonAsString=convertStreanToString(urlConnect.inputStream)
                publishProgress(dataJsonAsString)
            }catch (ex:Exception){

            }

            return  ""
        }


        override fun onProgressUpdate(vararg values:String?) {

            val json=JSONObject(values[0])
            val query= json.getJSONObject("identification")
            val sunrise=query.getString("id")
            flighttext.text="sunrise time" + sunrise

        }
        override fun onPostExecute(result: String?) {
            super.onPostExecute(result)
        }

        fun convertStreanToString(inputStream:InputStream):String{
            val  bufferReader = BufferedReader(InputStreamReader(inputStream))
            var line:String
            var allstring:String=""

            try {
                do {
                    line=bufferReader.readLine()
                    if(line!=null)
                        allstring+=line
                }while (line!=null)
                bufferReader.close()
            }catch (ex:Exception){}


            return allstring
        }

    }

//مالنا شغل ببيها
    override fun onBackPressed() {
        if (drawer_layout.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer_layout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START)
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed()
        }
    }
```

[my data json url](http://jsoneditoronline.org/?id=57eef4e4f8227fd4544d9decf8b37b3d)

Comment: where you are using JSONArray object?

Comment: i delete JSONArray object because i get error and problem when run app , so i want someone to edit my code and give my short answer pls .

Comment: show your json output

Comment: http://jsoneditoronline.org/?id=57eef4e4f8227fd4544d9decf8b37b3d

Comment: and what error it was giving?

Comment: you need availability array right?

Comment: i delete the code i get the error from him , and keep only JSONObject

Comment: yes i want availability array

Comment: try this code  json.getJSONArray("availability")

Answer (score 2):

here is how to fetch availability array from this response.

> {   "identification": {
>       "id": "f7c2de9",
>       "row": 4606622416,
>       "number": {
>         "default": "QR402",
>         "alternative": null
>       },
>       "callsign": "QTR402"   },   "availability": [
>       "AGE",
>       "MSN"   ] }

```
    val json=JSONObject(values[0])
    val availabilityArray = json.getJSONArray("availability")
```

your code should be like

```
 fun buclick(view:View){
        val flightSearch=editText2.text.toString()
        val url="xxxxxxx-flight=$flightSearch"
    MyAsyncTask().execute(url)
    }


    inner  class  MyAsyncTask:AsyncTask<String,String,String>(){

        override fun onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute()
        }

        override fun doInBackground(vararg p0: String?): String {
            //تمرير بيانات هنا
            try {
                val url=URL(p0[0])
                val urlConnect = url.openConnection() as HttpURLConnection
                urlConnect.connectTimeout=500

                val dataJsonAsString=convertStreanToString(urlConnect.inputStream)
                publishProgress(dataJsonAsString)
                val json=JSONObject(dataJsonAsString);
                ///here is the required array
                val availabilityArray = json.getJSONArray("availability")
                val query= json.getJSONObject("identification")
                val sunrise=query.getString("id")
                flighttext.text="sunrise time" + sunrise
            }catch (ex:Exception){

            }

            return  ""
        }


        override fun onProgressUpdate(vararg values:String?) {

//update progressbar


        }
        override fun onPostExecute(result: String?) {
            super.onPostExecute(result)
        }

        fun convertStreanToString(inputStream:InputStream):String{
            val  bufferReader = BufferedReader(InputStreamReader(inputStream))
            var line:String
            var allstring:String=""

            try {
                do {
                    line=bufferReader.readLine()
                    if(line!=null)
                        allstring+=line
                }while (line!=null)
                bufferReader.close()
            }catch (ex:Exception){}


            return allstring
        }

    }

//مالنا شغل ببيها
    override fun onBackPressed() {
        if (drawer_layout.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer_layout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START)
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed()
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

try below code

```
val availabilityArray = json.getJSONArray("availability")

        for (i in 0 until availabilityArray.length()){
            val winspeed = availabilityArray.getString(i);
            text.setText(winspeed)
        }
```